# Changing background of TinyMCE editor dynamically using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce

I have a comment field and an input textarea that is a tinymce editor. I have a checkbox named admin only and if that checkbox is clicked the body of tinymce should change color to pink and if it is not ticked it should be white. I used javascript and used onclick method to change it dynamically.

Here is the html code:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><span>New Comment :</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <textarea></textarea>
    </tr>
</table>
<div>
    <div align="left">
        <input name="cbAdmin" type="checkbox" id="cbAdmin" value="Admin" onClick="SetCommentColor()"/>
        <label>Administrator Only</label>
    </div>
```

And here is the javascript used :

```
function SetCommentColor() {
    if (document.form2.cbAdmin.checked == true) { 
        color = 'pink';
    } else {
        color = 'white';
    }
    var t = tinyMCE.getInstanceById('eComment');
    t.getBody().style.backgroundColor = color;
}
```

This doesnt work for me. Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Define - _"This doesnt work for me"_. What error do you see in your console?

Comment: The error on console is "TypeError: tinyMCE.getInstanceById is not a function detail.php:145"

Comment: Are you including the library? ----> `<script src="http://tinymce.cachefly.net/4.1/tinymce.min.js"></script>`. If not, add this `<script>` tag in your `<head>` tags.

Comment: i have the js in my local directory. i tried commenting my local js and added ur script i lost the tinymce editor on the textarea and can only see a normal textarea and not tinymce editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is final version of the code.

```html
<script type="application/javascript">
  tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    plugins: [
      "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
      "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
      "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste"
    ],
    toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image"
  });

  function SetCommentColor() {
    if (document.getElementById('cbAdmin').checked == true) {
      color = 'pink';
    } else {
      color = 'red';
    }
    //alert(tinyMCE.getInstanceById('eComment'));
    var t = tinyMCE.get(0);
    t.getBody().style.backgroundColor = color;
  }

</script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td><span>New Comment :</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <textarea id="eComment" name="eComment"></textarea>
  </tr>
</table>
<div>
  <div align="left">
    <input name="cbAdmin" type="checkbox" id="cbAdmin" value="Admin" onClick="SetCommentColor()" />
    <label>Administrator Only</label>
    <table>
```

Issues are missing Id and getInstanceById is not supported.

You can run this example here http://fiddle.tinymce.com/

Comment: thanks a lot man! worked like a charm!! changing var t=tinyMCE.get(0) made it possible! :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess the issue lie at 
`document.form2.cbAdmin.checked == true`

try to change the 'white' color to something else and see if your condition is passing or not.

Thanks

Comment: which version of TinyMCE are you using because the above code works fine for me

Comment: btw, I cannot see eComment Id on the textarea. Make sure you add all the Ids/names properly

Comment: sorry, i removed the class and ids for easier understanding as my code is too complex than it may seem... i am using 4.1.6 version